# Feature 'top-level statements' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater. Godot Question

Tags: c#, collision, godot

I am trying to learn how to use Godot, as I find it easier to learn than Unity, and have been following [a tutorial on their official documentation page](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/your_first_game.html), I've managed to get to the
*'Preparing for Collisions'* section, and have created the `Hit` signal, however, when I linked the nodes together, it created the function, and I wrote the code it said to put into it:

```
public void OnPlayerBodyEntered(PhysicsBody2D body)
{
    Hide(); // Player disappears after being hit.
    EmitSignal("Hit");
    GetNode<CollisionShape2D>("CollisionShape2D").SetDeferred("disabled", true);
}
```

But when I run it and it gives this error:

```
Feature 'top-level statements' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater.
```

I assumed this meant I have to update C#, which I didn't think would be that much of an issue, I tried updating it through the `dotnet-sdk` thing, but I'm not really sure what it is or how it works, and cannot find any other way of updating it in Godot. I apologise if this is a stupid question, I'm very new to Godot. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if that's the snippet of code which produces the top-level statement error. Top-level statement errors usually come from, typically `Program.cs`, or the code file that contains the `Main` method.

Top-level statements were introduced with C# 9:
[MSDN - Top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements)

In order to enable C# 9.0 in your project, you need to edit your `.csproj` file and add the following:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Alternatively, you can use the following configuration to target the latest C# version, **currently** **10.0**:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 4):

While the language C# is fully supported in Godot, the integration of the IDE is not the best (OK, it is bad integration).

> I (...) have created the Hit signal, however, when I linked the nodes together, it created the function, and I wrote the code it said to put into it

The issue is that it created it in the wrong place. Godot adds the handler method at the end of the file. Which is not correct. It should be a method inside the class that shares name with the file. Move the method there.

Comment: Thanks, that was also a problem, but not the one with the error I posted, had to work that one out too, and yeah, I've noticed its not integrated the best, bit of a pain, thanks again for the help